# .net,mongodb: json reader was expecting a value but found 'db'

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

getting json reader was expecting a value but found 'db' .net error while passing a query from c# to mongodb.

below is the code.

```
mquery="db.getcollection('colname').find({mesgid:{$in:['m1','m2']}}, 
{"_id":1},{"mesgId":1})";
var cmd= new JsonCommand<BasonDocument>(mquery);
var monclient=new MongoClient(constring);
var res=monclient.GetDatabase("db_name").RunCommand(cmd);
```

when the debugger hits RunCommand, then it is throwing " json reader was expecting a value but found 'db'" error.
can anyone help me out here.

Comment: `db.getcollection('colname').find({mesgid:{$in:['m1','m2']}},{"_id":1},{"mesgId":1})` is not a valid JSON, but a JavaScript command. `RunCommand` requires a JSON structure. Why don't you send the query using  of the `Find*` methods of the collection?

Comment: i am new these mongo and .net actuly, @Markus correct me if i am wrong! but we cant pass the raw query through Find method right?

Comment: Yes, much easier. See https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.16/getting_started/quick_tour/

Comment: c# builds filters differently, you are using the filter style for JavaScript and Python with c# code. Consider their course on c#/.NET to get started (free): https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M220N/about

Comment: You also have this tutorial https://github.com/iso8859/learn-mongodb-by-example